# Building a timetable in Windows API with C

Tags: c, winapi, opengl, timetable

Making a simple program where the user inputs different classes, times and dates, and a timetable is generated (like a timetable with university classes). I've worked with Windows API for basic applications however I cannot find a way to display all the information in a timetable chart.

Something like this:

[image]

Is there a function that can be used in Windows API for displaying a timetable, or will I have to work with graphics to generate an image of a timetable (using OpenGL for instance)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are programming in Win32 mode, to use ListView control is a better choice. You could get references from msdn: [ListView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369763(v=vs.85).aspx)
You can also use the TextOut api to print information onto your Window form.

Comment: Is it possible to split/merge the boxes in the listview table at runtime (ex: a specific course extends over a couple hours), and add colours as well?

Comment: You can sort items in your program first. Then refresh them onto listview and cover elder items. There are some structures we can use to adjust columns in a listview. Please search these key words on msdn web page: LV_ITEM, LV_COLUMN. And you can also use subclassing technic to achieve these feature.